# is it safe to hide and show page content based on login state using jquery? (All content in single page including the login/registration form)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Ok, I am building this web application where all of the content is placed in a single html file. In term of security and user experience, is it best practice to hide and show page content based on login state. For example:

- The user accessing the page with general content displayed.
- The page has a certain service that is available only to registered users.
- This service is coded in the same html file but I used CSS and jquery to hide it.
- Once the user tries to access this service, a login form (which is also coded in the same html file and hidden with the same way mentioned in the previous point) will show up.
- The login information is sent (via AJAX) to the server, handled (via PHP), and return a state.
- Based on this state either the service (or content) will be shown or remains hidden (if the state return doesn't indicate valid authentication).
- If the state indicates a success login, the service will be displayed by manipulating the DOM via jquery (using .show() function).

Keep in mind all of the aforementioned contents (service, login, general display of web site for non-users, content specifically displayed for users only) are all in single page but separated in different divs and hidden using CSS (display attribute) and jquery (using show() and hide() functions). So there is no actual redirecting or loading. I'm using html, CSS, jquery, and PHP for server side. Regarding security and user experience, is this approach considered as good practice or not? if not please advise

*Sorry for not including any codes. The web-app is little bit big, and I don't want to lose you while reading it. Thank you for your help and understanding in advance

Comment: If the (restricted) content is just hidden via css, then _any_ user can see it. (some bad coded online news do it this way for paywall articles, though. To my luck)

Comment: Sound like a terrible practice, just awful. But anyway this question is too broad, please read [ask]

Comment: It also sounds like you just set a client-side flag, which also can be manipulated by the user very easily.

Comment: Any user can execute CSS/JS to have the content display

Comment: Thank you all for responding. I understood this is not a good way to do it, what approach would you advise?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a good practice to use Javascript and Css to hide page content from users since anyone who knows how to use a browser console could easily show the hidden "secured" content.

You must at least prevent displaying the content of your secured page within php. After the user authenticates, you can display the content as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you utilise proper controls on PHP, so that if somebody unhide those elements using console not to be able to do anything more, then it is safe. Remember just because you hide it, does not mean nobody can see it.

Client-side hiding is okay as long as you have strong and proper server-side control. Safety comes from server-side controls, no matter what.

There was an story earlier this year about hackers manipulating a client-side-only verification to steal $170M from a website: https://www.reddit.com/r/Buttcoin/comments/7wrqsn/bitgrail_insolvency_due_to_people_editing/

Please ensure you are validating login status on each request. For example, if a user post something form a div that is supposed to be only shown to logged in users, you need to verify this login status from your PHP as well, and don't rely on what you receive from javascript.